# How to verify web service call is from android application or not

Tags: php, android, api, web-services, security

I have an android application with php web services. Web service urls are stored in application itself. I have a registration page in my application that post data to registration url.

My code for registration is :

```
           `String link = "http://xxxxxxx.registration.php";
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("name", "UTF-8") + "=" +
                    URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8");
            data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("phone", "UTF-8") + "=" +
                    URLEncoder.encode(phone, "UTF-8");
            data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" +
                    URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8"); 

            URL url = new URL(link);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(data);
            wr.flush();`
```

After i published the apk into playstore, someone reverse engineered the apk file and sending bulk requests with post data to my registration url.

I haven't used Proguard at the time of this attack.

```
minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro
```

I tried securing the urls by keeping it on the gradle.properties file and call it by BuildConfig.Registration_Url. by referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47175375/7482398). But somehow they find the url again.

After some search I came to know that there is no method that hide urls 100% from attacker

1. I would like to know what is the correct method to secure code from an attacker.
2. How can i Verify the web service request is from application or not(It should redirect to an error page if the call is not from the application)
3. Can i keep all the web service url in server side?

I am a beginner in programming. Please Help !

Comment: May be you'll get it from User-Agent. Not sure

Comment: @YashParekh Sorry, I didn't get you. User-Agent??

Comment: I'm talking about `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`

Comment: @YashParekh What can i do with `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: @YashParekh Thanks. Its Working. But what if i do when the attacker try posting data from the mobile device?

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer. It will help to others who have same problems. And can't get your last question??

Comment: @YashParekh Thanks for the answer. My actual problem is an attacker sending bulk request to my registration url with post data. So my question is what can i do, if he is able to do the same with his mobile device (Posting data to my registation url with his android device.).

Comment: @YashParekh already up voted, though my reputation is below 15.

Comment: You can deny request based on requests like allow limited request per time interval. Its okay for upvote but you can accept also

Comment: @YashParekh  I would like to know the webservice url call is from my device. I tried saving a token in my app sending with the post data. But attacker is able to get the token.

Comment: @YashParekh  I want to know the url call is from my application. your answer only check if it is from android ,iphone...etc.

Comment: I don't have knowledge about android and Iphone. I just told you about the web-service and prevention from bulk request.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the user agent from `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`, 
and for simple detection you can use this [SCRIPT](http://www.schiffner.com/programming-php-classes/php-mobile-device-detection/):

```
<?php

//Detect special conditions devices
$iPod    = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");
$iPhone  = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
$iPad    = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPad");
$Android = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android");
$webOS   = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"webOS");

//do something with this information
if( $iPod || $iPhone ){
    //browser reported as an iPhone/iPod touch -- do something here
}else if($iPad){
    //browser reported as an iPad -- do something here
}else if($Android){
    //browser reported as an Android device -- do something here
}else if($webOS){
    //browser reported as a webOS device -- do something here
}

?>
```

If you want to know more details of the user device I recommended to use one of the following solutions: http://51degrees.mobi or http://deviceatlas.com